# SLA serial number can only be numeric

Tags: formula, custom-field, validation, validation-rule

I have to create validation rule where SLA is GOLD, should have a value and also SLA serial number can only be numeric.
I have written this way

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( SLA__c , 'Gold'), ISBLANK(SLASerialNumber__c ),
IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(SLASerialNumber__c )))
)
```

Which gives me the error:

> Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the `IF`. `NOT` returns a `Boolean` result, as does `ISNUMBER`.

From the [Visualforce Developer Guide | Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm):

> **Function** `NOT`
> **Description** Returns `FALSE` for `TRUE` and `TRUE` for `FALSE`.
> **Use** `NOT(logical)` and replace `logical` with the expression that you want evaluated.
>
> **Function**: `ISNUMBER`
> **Description** Determines if a text value is a number and returns `TRUE` if it is. Otherwise, it returns `FALSE`.
> **Use** `ISNUMBER(text)` and replace `text` with the merge field name for the text field.

So `NOT(ISNUMBER(SLASerialNumber__c))` will yield `TRUE` (error case) if the serial number is not a number.

---

While the above advice will get your formula to compile, you should note that you are validating when the field is blank and this condition arises. **You need the two conditions on the serial number to be joined with `OR`.**

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(SLA__c, 'Gold'),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(SLASerialNumber__c),
        NOT(ISNUMBER(SLASerialNumber__c))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out!!!  So we need to use OR as there are two conditions.

Comment: @user If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: You need to use both `AND` and `OR`. For the serial number part, though, you do need `OR` because you can't have both error conditions at the same time. @user

Comment: The logic is not working even after I entered Only numeric when SLA is 'GOLD'

Comment: It is showing the same error if I entered 'AB1111' or '1111'

Comment: When I tried yesterday there was some confusion. but now I tried again it's working. can you tell me how it works when we edit layout and make SLA and SLA serial number required and non-required ?